# uploading form and image with php to mysql odd error

Tags: php, mysql, image, forms

I'm trying to upload a form with an image using PHP to MySQL. I keep however, getting this error -

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/content/03/6455003/html/leakfaucet/submitAlbumForm.php on line 17
```

I've been staring at this one for quite a while now and just can't figure out what the issue is, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Form-

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Submit an Album</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Submit an Album</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="submitAlbumForm.php" method="post">
        <tr>
          <td>Artist Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="artistName" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Album Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="albumName" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Release Date</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="releaseDate" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>        
        <tr>
          <td>Leak Date</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="leakDate" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Where It Leaked</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="whereItLeaked" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Album Cover</td>
          <td><input type="file" name="albumCover">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>        
          <td></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Upload script

```
<?php
include "base.php";

//Setting up images directory
 $target = "images/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

 $albumCover=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

//inserting data order
$order = "INSERT INTO albums
            (artistName, albumName, releaseDate, leakDate, whereItLeaked, albumCover)
            VALUES
            ('$_POST[artistName]',
            '$_POST[albumName]',
            '$_POST[releaseDate]',
            '$_POST[leakDate]',
            '$_POST[whereItLeaked]',
            '($_FILES['albumCover']['name'])')";  /*this is the line where the error keeps occurring. I've tried a number of variations and still can't seem to get it right*/

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['albumCover']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives an error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 

//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
if($result){
    echo("<br>Thank you for submitting!");
} else{
    echo("<br>Sorry, something went wrong! Please try again!");
}
?>
```

My base.php file with connect info

```
<?php
session_start();

$dbhost = "";
$dbname = "";
$dbuser = "";
$dbpass = "";

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use quoted array keys in PHP double-quoted strings. It throws warnings. Plus, you cannot use multi-dimensional arrays as you are within double-quoted strings. PHP's parser is not "greedy" and will only see a single level of array, e.g.

```
$foo = array();
$foo['bar'] = array();
$foo['bar']['baz'] = 'fizzbuzz';
echo "$foo['bar']['baz']";
```

will issue a warning about the quoted keys, and the ouput would actually be:

```
Array['baz']
```

because the second level of array is not seen by PHP.

You need to use the `{}` notation:

```
'({$_FILES['albumCover']['name']})')";
  ^---                          ^---
```

which both allows quoted array keys, and forces PHP to consider the ENTIRE array reference, not just the first level.

Beyond that, your code is gaping wide open for [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you should read up and learn how to avoid those before you put this code on a public facing web-site, otherwise enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Ah thank you so much! Yes I still have a long way to go with studying security haha. Thank you very much for the help and advice!

Comment: Putting quotes around things and then praying **really hard** that nobody puts a `'` in a filename is not really an answer, but at least you make a note of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
get values into variables use mysql_real_escape_string

```
 $artist_name =mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['artistName']);
 $albumname=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['albumName'] );
 $releaseDate=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['releaseDate']);
...

"INSERT INTO albums
        (artistName, albumName, releaseDate, leakDate, whereItLeaked, albumCover)
        VALUES ( '$artist_name', '$albumname',...)"
```